# Multiple duplicates in average price after grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to produce a list of drugs and their average price.

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[drugPurchases](
    [importId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [importDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [rxNumber] [float] NULL,
    [accountNumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [lastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [firstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [dob] [datetime] NULL,
    [ssn] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [drugName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [drugStrength] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [dosage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [quantityDispensed] [float] NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
    [facilityCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [fillDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [processed] [bit] NOT NULL
```

Some sample data for a specific drug called "ENALAPRIL".

```
select
    drugName,
    drugStrength,
    dosage,
    quantityDispensed,
    price
from 
    drugPurchases 
where 
    drugName = 'ENALAPRIL' 
    and drugStrength = '10MG' 
    and fillDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Result:

```
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 180 3.42
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 120 2.28
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 240 31.18
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 300 38.97
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 240 31.18
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 120 15.59
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 120 15.59
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  1.14
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 60  7.79
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 180 3.42
```

My goal is to get the average price of ENALAPRIL, for each strength. My query is:

```
SELECT
    distinct(drugName),
    drugStrength,
    dosage,
    ROUND(price / quantityDispensed, 2) as 'calc'
FROM
    drugPurchases
where
    fillDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
    and drugName = 'ENALAPRIL'
    and drugStrength = '10MG'
GROUP BY
    drugName,
    drugStrength,
    dosage,
    (price / quantityDispensed)
ORDER BY
    drugName,
    drugStrength
```

But my result set is yielding two different prices for ENALAPRIL 10MG:

```
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 0.02
ENALAPRIL   10MG    TAB 0.13
```

Any idea why it is doing this and how I might need to adjust my query?

Comment: It's doing this because there are two different 'calc' prices. 1.14/60 yields 0.019 (0.02 when rounded), and 7.79/60 = 0.1289something, or 0.13. I tried a few other variations, and they all came down to one of those two numbers. In short, the producer of the drugs has two different prices when it comes to the different quantities per penny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is grouping by two separate entries in drugpurchases as a result of this in your group by...

```
(price / quantityDispensed)
```

You could aggregate these two values using SUM(price/quantityDispensed) and remove the group by.

```
SELECT
    drugName,
    drugStrength,
    dosage,
    ROUND(
    Avg(price / quantityDispensed), 2) as 'calc'
FROM
    drugPurchases
where
    fillDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
    and drugName = 'ENALAPRIL'
    and drugStrength = '10MG'
GROUP BY
    drugName,
    drugStrength,
    dosage,
ORDER BY
    drugName,
    drugStrength
```

Comment: I agree, but you can also drop the distinct() as it's redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer tworoswell, but doing a manual calculation, I am  seeing a total of 2,460 `quantityDispensed` with a total cost of $226.37 which comes to an average price of $.09. Your answer comes up with a price of $2.12 per dose.

Comment: You need to average the sums, not take the sum of the averages:     ROUND(SUM(price) / sum(quantityDispensed), 2) as 'calc'

Comment: Or just use avg instead of sum. I have made a change to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by price/quantity, so every price/quantity result will produce a seperate row returned.  Use an aggregate in the price/quantity and remove it from the group by.  I hope this has the same results:

```
SELECT
   distinct(drugName),
   drugStrength,
   dosage,
   ROUND(avg(price / quantityDispensed), 2) as 'calc'
FROM
   drugPurchases
where
   fillDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
   and drugName = 'ENALAPRIL'
   and drugStrength = '10MG'
GROUP BY
   drugName,
   drugStrength,
   dosage
ORDER BY
   drugName,
   drugStrength
```